# Sunspot not reading sunspot.yml when inside mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, rails-engines

I am using the sunspot gem inside a mountable engine. I am creating an engine out of an existing Rails 3.2 app so I know that my setup works when in a standard rails app.

Basically, I can't get Sunspot in development (when using spec/dummy - I know that it's normally used to for testing but everything else works just fine) to load the `sunspot.yml` file and find the running version of Solr.

My gemspec has:

```
s.add_dependency 'sunspot_rails', '= 2.0.0.pre.120417'
s.add_development_dependency 'sunspot_solr', '~> 1.3.3'
s.add_development_dependency 'sunspot_test', '~> 0.4.0'
```

My mountable engine has a dummy rails app at spec/dummy for testing. My spec/dummy/config/sunspot.yml contains:

```
development:
  solr:
    port: 8080
    path: /solr
    hostname: localhost
```

When I run a rails console (from inside spec/dummy) with `bundle exec rails console` I get a normal rails console.

Running `Sunspot.config` produces:

```
> Sunspot.config
=> #<LightConfig::Configuration:0x007f864aeee8a0
 @properties=
  {:solr=>
    #<LightConfig::Configuration:0x007f864aeed0b8
     @properties=
      {:url=>"http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr",
       :read_timeout=>nil,
       :open_timeout=>nil}>,
   :master_solr=>
    #<LightConfig::Configuration:0x007f864aefb398 @properties={:url=>nil}>,
   :pagination=>
    #<LightConfig::Configuration:0x007f864af06ae0
     @properties={:default_per_page=>30}>,
   :indexing=>
    #<LightConfig::Configuration:0x007f864af0bf18
     @properties={:default_batch_size=>50}>}>
```

Clearly Sunspot isn't picking up my `sunspot.yml` file because the port is running on `8983` instead of `8080` where it's actually running.

Starting the Solr server via `bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start` (inside spec/dummy) or `bundle exec rake app:sunspot:solr:start` (from root of engine) starts the server correctly on port `8080` so I know that that is reading `sunspot.yml`

There are few other people with similar questions but I'm not using the `sunspot_mongoid` gem and feel like it's something to do with the fact it's running inside an engine.

If anyone could give me a hand it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say what's wrong here, but I can tell you that I am doing the same thing -- making an engine out of rails app -- and that I have solr 2.0.0-pre-something and now 2.1.0 working in all environments locally and deployed.  So, it can work.

I guess I would move forward by reading through the code involved in starting solr and how it goes about finding the config.

Not super helpful, overall -- but at least there's a reply now that suggests you're not doomed. :)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the answer to this. Adding `s.add_development_dependency 'sunspot_solr', '~> 1.3.3'` adds `sunspot_solr` to the development profile only to the gem - not when you are running an application containing the gem in development mode. This makes sense for a 'normal' gem - I just wasn't thinking straight.

So in order to get the gem into your app containing the engine, you ether to have it as a normal `add_dependency` or include it in the app's `Gemfile`.

Sorry for wasting your time @ian

Dave